# Signing an Appcelerator Titaniun App on a different machine

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

How can we sign a Titanium app on a different machine than the one which is was developed on?

Basically, signing with the enterprise cert is centralized while development is distributed. So we wrote the app on one machine and now we need to sign it with the Enterprise cert on another machine.

Comment: It doesn't depend on machine, if you are able to sign the build on the machine which you are using for development, then in the same way you can sing the app from any machine.

Comment: I believe that it does. When we move the project to the signing machine. We open up the project in Xcode. We attempt to build the project and we get the following error.. "/usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory"

Comment: have you configured the signing machine same as dev machine?

Comment: No.. Its just a machine used for signing all apps within the organisation

Comment: Then you should install Titanium on the signing machine and configure it same as the dev machine. I think by doing this your problem will be solved.

Comment: The question is do I 'NEED' to .. I understand that I CAN install it, but if the app signing is centralized, no one in their right might would want to install it on a machine used to just sign apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Swandand that it does not depend on the machine. The easiest way is really to use a source control system (e.g. Git) and just use that as the "central" place to keep your code - and just check out, modify, test, and commit as needed :-)

If you use Git then you should also use Git Flow and this way you can build a new version for production and then that is the version you sign and ship.

/John

Answer (score 0):

You do need the machine to have the private key and the related certificate and provisioning profile. Export them from the other machine as p12 using KeyChain.

Comment: Its actually not a issue with the 'keys'. Its an issue with building the project. When we attempt to build on the second machine ( without Titanium installed ) we get '/usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory'

Comment: You need Titanium installed on every Machine you build on... plus keys

Comment: Hmm.. Thats what I feared. Do you have a reference to review?

Comment: Reference? Guide you mean? It's simple, to build a Titanium app, you need Titanium. And sinds Titanium in the end builds an XCode projects and signs it through xcode command line tools, you need the keys.

Comment: Sorry.. By 'reference' I was hoping to get some sort of documentation stating that you have to install appcelerator on every machine you want to build it on ( even building it directly on Xocde ).. Thanks